# indexOf always returning true for document.location

Tags: javascript, dom

I have the following script:

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('env=P')) {      
  env = 'P';
  console.log("P");
} else {
  env = 'A';
  console.log("A");
}
```

env is always equal to P no matter what the url is.  I am quite sure I have used indexOf before for uri's but am not sure the issue here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because indexOf doesn't return 0 and is therefore evaluated as true. Try changing to

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('env=P') > -1)
```

Answer (score 4):

`indexOf` will return `-1` if the substring is not in the string, and `-1` is a `true` value.

This is because it returns the index of the substring (so it is `'foo'.indexOf('f')` that would return `0`).

Your check should be:

```
if (location.href.indexOf('env=P') >= 0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

`indexOf` returns -1 if there is no match, thats a Truthy value, you need to be explicit;

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('env=P') === -1) {   
  ///no match
```