# Hide Div if Other Div contains Text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var message = document.getElementById("es_msg_pg");
var videos =  document.getElementById("x-section-2");

if (message.innerHTML.indexOf("Email Address already exists!") {
   videos.style.display = "block";
 } else {
   videos.style.display = "none";
 }
}
```

This seemed to be so straight forward but it's not working on my website.
Any suggestions?

Here is the HTML I am trying to check if it contains the text Email Address already exists!

```
<div class="es_msg" id="es_shortcode_msg">
<span id="es_msg_pg"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error and a logic error. `if (message.innerHTML.indexOf("Email Address already exists!")` -> `if (message.innerHTML.indexOf("Email Address already exists!") > -1)`

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis in your `if` and you have an extra closing bracket at the very end. Try fixing those and see if it works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [indexOf always returning true for document.location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929027/indexof-always-returning-true-for-document-location)

Comment: My apologies, but I am very new to javascript and I didn't understand the proposed question or how it related to my problem. Now that I see the answers here I can draw a correlation. Sorry if I have wasted anyone's time.

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf` returns a number. The number is the position of a string in another string, starting at `0`. If the string doesn't exist, then it returns `-1`, which evaluates to `true`. You want to compare the the return value like this:

```
if (message.innerHTML.indexOf("Email Address already exists!") >= 0) { ... }
```

Comment: How do you loop this?
Right now the function works, but I would need to loop it so that once they do type in an email the content would show. Right now it stays hidden because, on the page load, there is no entry in the email field.

Comment: You don't really need a loop. You just need to rerun the code when the value in the email field changes. You can do this by putting everything in a function like `function refreshDiv() { /* Your code here */ }` and then call that function using `refreshDiv();` whenever the value in the email field changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```js
var message = document.getElementById("es_msg_pg");
var videos =  document.getElementById("es_shortcode_msg");
console.log(message.innerHTML);

// returns -1 if message doesnt contain your custom text
if (message.innerHTML.indexOf("Email Address already exists!") == -1) 
 {
   videos.style.display = "block";
 } else 
 {
   videos.style.display = "none";
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="es_msg" id="es_shortcode_msg">
<span id="es_msg_pg">Email Address already exists!</span>
</div>
<div>Hello</div>
```

Comment: your welcome :) please consider accept true answer to help people understand question has been solved

Comment: I wish I could, it is saying my reputation is too low...
Do you know how to loop this, so once a person puts in an email address the script will be played through? Right now it only works if I manually enter it in the console log.

Comment: I didnt understand you well, are you trying to create dynamic text to use it in if condition?